# Generalized OU process and Poisson random measure

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, levy-processes

If I consider $X_t$ is a generalized Ornstein uhlenbeck process, how I can prove that 
$$\text{sign}\left(X_t\right). N(dt,du)$$ is a Poisson measure?
Same question if I consider the compensated Poisson random measure.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "generalized Ornstein Uhlenbeck process"?